# change the prompt in .net console application

Tags: .net, console-application

as an example, if you use the command tool NSLOOKUP by simply typing:

```
c:>nslookup
```

then it outputs your default server and address as well as changing the prompt to:

```
>
```

I'm looking to subdivide some sections of my console app and would like the user to know when they're in a subsection. E.g.:

```
c:>myConsoleApp -servers
servers>find host=hostName
switch to=apps
apps>
```

and so on.

How do I change those prompts?

Comment: The prompt is displayed by cmd.exe, the command line processor.  It is out of the picture once your app starts, everything the user sees is now what your program displays.  You can do anything you want, a custom "prompt" is simply whatever you write with Console.Write() before you call Console.ReadLine().

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for that, I tested it and it works. If you want to go ahead and put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.